# Show tif/tiff image in android

Tags: java, android, image, tiff

im trying to show .tif image in android using glide. but after some searching I realise that android didn't support tif/tiff format. to resolve that im using that library which is [Android-TiffBitmapFactory](https://github.com/Beyka/Android-TiffBitmapFactory).

that seems to be good and its documentation is also easy.
when I trying implement this in my code it gives always null bitmap.

I dont know what goes wrong. so please help me how can I do that . and one more thing can i embed this library with glide so that i don't need to download and then use from storage.

just directly like normal image.

and here's my code for that

```
 File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/MyEx.tif");
   TiffBitmapFactory.Options options = new TiffBitmapFactory.Options();
     thread = new Thread(() -> {
          bitmap =  TiffBitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, options);;
          if(bitmap != null) {
              thread.interrupt();
              Log.d(TAG, "run: " + "thread stopped" + bitmap);
          }
     });
   Glide.with(context) .load(bitmap)
   .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) .into(sdp);
```

---

Comment: Hello, we've got the exact same issue. Did you solve it? @Tanveerbyn